# How to assemble two different array in one array of php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1 = Array ( [0] => 5 [days] => 5 )
        Array ( [0] => 6 [days] => 6 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 7 [days] => 7 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 8 [days] => 8 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 9 [days] => 9 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 10 [days] => 10 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 11 [days] => 11 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 12 [days] => 12 )
        Array ( [0] => 13 [days] => 13 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 14 [days] => 14 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 15 [days] => 15 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 16 [days] => 16 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 17 [days] => 17 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 18 [days] => 18 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 19 [days] => 19 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 20 [days] => 20 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 21 [days] => 21 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 22 [days] => 22 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 23 [days] => 23 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 24 [days] => 24 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 25 [days] => 25 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 26 [days] => 26 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 27 [days] => 27 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 28 [days] => 28 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 29 [days] => 29 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 30 [days] => 30 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 31 [days] => 31 );

$arr2 = Array ( [0] => 1 [day] => 1 
                [1] => 1 [days] => 1 ) 
        Array ( [0] => 2 [day] => 2 [1] => 2 [days] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 [day] => 3 [1] => 3 [days] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 4 [day] => 4 [1] => 4 [days] => 4 );
```

i want to ascending-ly marge `$arr1` and `$arr2` and the output i expect

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31`

help me How can i do like that?

Comment: Please format your question so it's easy to read.

Comment: If this is REAL output, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It would be easier to deal with this array if you change your fetch to just a `fetch_assoc()` or equivalent in which ever extension you are usng. Then you would only get each data item shown ONCE instead of TWICE

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array(0=>Array ( 0 => 5 ,'days' => 5 ) ,
        1=>Array ( 0 => 6 ,'days' => 6 ),
        2=>Array ( 0 => 7 ,'days' => 7 ),
        3=>Array ( 0 => 8 ,'days' => 8 ),
        4=>Array ( 0 => 9, 'days' => 9 ),
        5=>Array ( 0 => 10, 'days' => 10 ),
        6=>Array ( 0 => 11, 'days' => 11 ),
        7=>Array ( 0 => 12, 'days' => 12 ),
        8=>Array ( 0 => 13, 'days' => 13 ),
        9=>Array ( 0 => 14, 'days' => 14 ),
        10=>Array ( 0 => 15, 'days' => 15 ),
        11=>Array ( 0 => 16, 'days' => 16 ),
        12=>Array ( 0 => 17, 'days' => 17 ),
        13=>Array ( 0 => 18, 'days' => 18 ),
        14=>Array ( 0 => 19, 'days' => 19 ),
        15=>Array ( 0 => 20, 'days' => 20 ),
        16=>Array ( 0 => 21, 'days' => 21 ),
        17=>Array ( 0 => 22, 'days' => 22 ),
        18=>Array ( 0 => 23, 'days' => 23 ),
        19=>Array ( 0 => 24, 'days' => 24 ),
        20=>Array ( 0 => 25, 'days' => 25 ),
        21=>Array ( 0 => 26, 'days' => 26 ),
        22=>Array ( 0 => 27, 'days' => 27 ),
        23=>Array ( 0 => 28, 'days' => 28 ),
        24=>Array ( 0 => 29, 'days' => 29 ),
        25=>Array ( 0 => 30, 'days' => 30 ),
        26=>Array ( 0 => 31 ,'days' => 31 ));

$arr2 = Array(0=>Array( 0 => 1, 'day' => 1, 1 => 1, 'days' => 1 ) ,
    1=> Array ( 0 => 2, 'day' => 2, 1 => 2, 'days' => 2 ) ,
    3=>Array ( 0 => 3, 'day' => 3, 1 => 3 ,'days' => 3 ) ,
    4=>Array ( 0 => 4 ,'day' => 4, 1 => 4 ,'days' => 4 ));

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
            $arr2[$key]=array_unique($value);
}
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        $arr1[$key]=array_unique($value);
}
$new=array_merge($arr2,$arr1);
foreach ($new as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo $value[0].",";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_column** to select only **days** from the multi dimensional array and then use **array_merge** to merge the array.

Just like this

```
$merger=array_merge(array_column($arr2,'days'),array_column($arr1,'days'));
$merger=implode(',',$merger);
```

It will produce your desired out put.